# How can I find out which process in Ubuntu is using maximum memory and CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, process, resources

Once in a while my Ubuntu desktop becomes slow because of a particular process.

How can I find out from the command line which process is consuming the maximum memory and CPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use the tools "top" or "htop".